# How to get static libraries for Eclipse Paho MQTT C client?

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, static-linking, paho

I'm trying to compile the code from the [Paho repository](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c) on Ubuntu 16.04, such that the static libraries are produced:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c.git
mkdir /tmp/build.paho
cd /tmp/build.paho
cmake -GNinja -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=TRUE -DPAHO_BUILD_STATIC=TRUE ~/Downloads/paho.mqtt.c
```

The procedure always fails with the following errors:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- CMake version: 3.5.1
-- CMake system name: Linux
-- Timestamp is 2019-10-22T09:16:51Z
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:95 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  add_library cannot create target "paho-mqtt3c" because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a shared library created in source directory "/home/<username>/Downloads/paho.mqtt.c/src".  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.

CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:96 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  add_library cannot create target "paho-mqtt3a" because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a shared library created in source directory "/home/<username>/Downloads/paho.mqtt.c/src".  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.

CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:101 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for shared library target "paho-mqtt3c".

-- OpenSSL hints: 
-- OpenSSL headers found at /usr/include
-- OpenSSL library found at /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
-- OpenSSL Crypto library found at /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:165 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  add_library cannot create target "paho-mqtt3cs" because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a shared library created in source directory "/home/<username>/Downloads/paho.mqtt.c/src".  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.

CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:166 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  add_library cannot create target "paho-mqtt3as" because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a shared library created in source directory "/home/<username>/Downloads/paho.mqtt.c/src".  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.

CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:176 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for shared library target "paho-mqtt3cs".

-- OpenSSL hints: 
-- OpenSSL headers found at /usr/include
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/<username>/Downloads/paho.mqtt.c/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I don't understand what is going wrong. To my understanding I'm exactly following the steps of the repository documentation.

What else do I have to do, or what do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this repository, the static library target names conflict with the shared library target names. CMake does not allow this, as the target names must be *unique*. It looks like these ill-advised changes were pushed to the repository, which broke the PAHO CMake build (see [here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/commit/8cc51c78b76a1eabd1df3124b0887ce8b01070ff#diff-95e351a3805a1dafa85bf20b81d086e6)). Since the issue has been raised, one would assume a fix will be pushed soon.

If you need a quick fix however, it is fairly painless to get this working. You can add the `-static` postfix onto the static library names in the `paho.mqtt.c/src/CMakeLists.txt` file. There are two notable sections in which this change need to happen, just search that file for `PAHO_BUILD_STATIC`:

Near [line 94](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/9f7f45c76c02abee18766ca64c482ba036d0cb2c/src/CMakeLists.txt#L94) (add `-static` to the library names referenced within the if-statement, in bold below):

```
IF (PAHO_BUILD_STATIC)
    ADD_LIBRARY(paho-mqtt3c-static STATIC $ MQTTClient.c)
    ADD_LIBRARY(paho-mqtt3a-static STATIC $ MQTTAsync.c)

    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(paho-mqtt3c-static ${LIBS_SYSTEM})
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(paho-mqtt3a-static ${LIBS_SYSTEM})

    INSTALL(TARGETS paho-mqtt3c-static paho-mqtt3a-static
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
ENDIF()
```

Near [line 164](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/9f7f45c76c02abee18766ca64c482ba036d0cb2c/src/CMakeLists.txt#L164) (add `-static` to the library names referenced within the if-statement, in bold below):

```
    IF (PAHO_BUILD_STATIC)
        ADD_LIBRARY(paho-mqtt3cs-static STATIC $ MQTTClient.c SSLSocket.c)
        ADD_LIBRARY(paho-mqtt3as-static STATIC $ MQTTAsync.c SSLSocket.c)

        TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(paho-mqtt3cs-static ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${LIBS_SYSTEM})
        TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(paho-mqtt3as-static ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${LIBS_SYSTEM})
        SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(
        paho-mqtt3cs-static paho-mqtt3as-static PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${CLIENT_VERSION}
        SOVERSION ${PAHO_VERSION_MAJOR}
        COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "OPENSSL=1")

        INSTALL(TARGETS paho-mqtt3cs-static paho-mqtt3as-static
            ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
    ENDIF()
```

After making the changes, clear your CMake cache (or delete the CMakeCache.txt file in your build folder) and re-run CMake. This should resolve the issue.